# Set layout template paths with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-print-layouts

Under Settings>Options>Layout>Layout Paths we can define *Path(s) to search for extra print templates* like shown here:

[image]

I intend to deploy an organization-wide standard path for print templates using PyQGIS in a startup-script but struggle in finding a method that does what I desire.

I cannot find something related in the `QgsSettings()`, but I found a method

```
QgsApplication.instance().layoutTemplatePaths()
```

*returning* a list of the currently defined print template paths, but no equivalent method `setLayoutTemplatePaths()`.

How may I set these print template paths using PyQGIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values are in the QGIS3.ini and under QGIS, in the properties > Advanced tab > `core` > `Layout` > `searchPathsForTemplates`.

I modify the values with the following code :

```
new_template_dir = "/home/me/my_custom_template_dir"
app = QgsApplication.instance()
params = QgsSettings(
    app.qgisSettingsDirPath() + "QGIS/QGIS3.ini", QSettings.IniFormat
)
params.beginGroup("/core/Layout")
# retrieve the current directories
existing_dir = params.value("searchPathsForTemplates")
# append the new one in the list
if existing_dir is None:
    existing_dir = [new_template_dir]
elif isinstance(existing_dir, str):
    if new_template_dir != existing_dir:
        existing_dir = [existing_dir, new_template_dir]
    else:
        existing_dir = [existing_dir]
elif isintance(existing_dir, list):
    if new_template_dir not in existing_dir:
        existing_dir.append(new_template_dir)

# setting the new list
params.setValue("searchPathsForTemplates", existing_dir)
```

The code can be improved by verifying the `new_template_dir` exists for example but for me, it works.

Comment: It should be noted, that in cases of exactly *one* template path `existing_dir` will be a string, not a one-element-list as one might expect which throws a traceback in the `...append()` line

Comment: And furthermore, if *no* template path is specified, we'll get an empty list. A bit weird me thinks.

Comment: I've improved the code.

Comment: This is a bit like code golf, but IMHO you can skip the test for `existing_dir == ""` because I think this never happens (correct me if I'm wrong, it's monday morning...) and replace the test for `list` with simply `else` ;-)

Comment: I replace it with `is None` test because in my QGIS, it was `None`, and I prefer to leave the `elif``with tests that readable and avoid `else` like an `except` without error type. But it's monday morning for me too !